# How to manage client/server session data using jersey 2.19 REST API

Tags: java, rest, session, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am new to REST and am trying to figure out an issue with giving access to users to the REST API data

I have an application where Users have limited rights to what they can see based on their user ID.
I do this through something similar to below:

```
    @Component
    public class StudentsResource{

        @Path("students")
        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public Students getStudents(@Context HttpServletRequest request){
            final HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            User user = (User) session.getAttribute(RestConstants.USER);

            if(user == null){
                throw new NotLoggedInException(RestConstants.USER_NOT_LOGGED_IN);
            }
            Students students = new Students();

            return students;
        }
    }
```

If I login to the application, and then paste the URL for the REST URL into the browser `localhost:8080/api/students` I get the JSON response of `/students`. If I don't login to the application first and instead just navigate to the URL `localhost:8080/api/students` in the browser, I get the error that I am not authorized because I am not logged into the application. (So that works just as I want)

However, if I build a webpage in the app that uses `client` code to call the API where pressing a button will run:

```
    String restURL = "http://localhost:8080/localhost:8080/api/students";
    final RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
    Students response = rest.getForObject(restURL,Students.class);
```

I then login to the app, and run the above code by pressing the button (instead of just navigating to the URL in the browser), I get an error that I am not logged in, so I do not have permission to see the data.

Upon further investigation, I saw that this is because the session that I am getting in my `server` side code has `null` for the logged in `user` when pressing the button on the `client` side, but it has the correct `user` when just navigating to the URL in the browser.

Why is this value `null` when using the `client` code if I logged in, but it works by navigating to the URL?

How can I get the correct `Session` data to get the logged in `user` when using the `Client` code/button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve client/server communication by token based authentication mechanism, basically what you do is after user login into our system, we generate a random UUid and concatenate it with userid,Encode it with Base64 algorithm  and send it back to client as a token,

Then from the next request onward the user need to send the token in the header, form the header we can identify which user is accessing the service.

for more information chekout the below link, it is a good blog for all the details regarding Jax-Rs

https://abhirockzz.wordpress.com/